# AWS Cloudformation: Cross Stack Reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following stack structure.

ParentStack:

- ChildStack1
- ChildStack2

What I need to do is to pass LambdaExecutionRole arn created in ChildStack2, having ChildStack2Name as a parameter, to ChildStack1.
Here are the snippets of my script

Parent Stack:

```
"Resources": {
    "ChildStack1": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
          "ChildStack2Name": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["ChildStack2", "Outputs.StackName"]}
         },
        ....
```

ChildStack1:

```
"Parameters" {
  "ChildStack2Name": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Name of commons stack"
    },
...
"Resources": {
  "Role": {
    HERE I NEED A LambdaExecutionRole ARN CREATED IN CHILDSTACK2
  }
}
```

ChildStack2

```
"Resources": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
       .....
    }
}
"Outputs": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
       "Value": {"Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "LambdaExecutionRole" ]]},
      "Export": {
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "LambdaExecutionRole" ]]
        }
      }
    },
    "StackName": {
      "Value": {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},
      "Export": {
        "Name": {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to cloudformation and probably these snippets could be refactored in some way.

Thank you.

Comment: If the resource you'd like the attributes for was created in the cloudformation template, you can access certain properties in the return values using [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html), but this will vary by resource.

Comment: Post some more details, like the stack or relevant excerpts from it.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry, I misunderstood the problem, so I changed the topic name and provided additional code snippets. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should output the LambdaExecutionRole's ARN from the template. Example below is assuming the resource `LambdaExecutionRole` in ChildStack2 is an `AWS::IAM::Role` type and the output name is `LambdaExecutionRoleARN`.

```
"Outputs": {
  "LambdaExecutionRole": {
     "Value": {"Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "LambdaExecutionRole" ]]},
    "Export": {
      "Name": {
        "Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "LambdaExecutionRole" ]]
      }
    }
  },
  "LambdaExecutionRoleARN": {
     "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"]}
  },
```

Next, in ChildStack1, add another parameter to hold the ARN value that will be passed from Parent Stack. Then you can `Ref` the parameter into `Role` resource.

```
"Parameters" {
    "ChildStack2Name": {
       "Type": "String",
       "Description": "Name of commons stack"
    },
    "LambdaExecutionRoleArn": {
       "Type": "String",
       "Description": "Lambda Execution Role's ARN"
    },
  ...
  "Resources": {
    "Role": {
       // Here use { "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRoleArn"} to get the value of the parameters
  }
}
```

Then in your Parent Stack, you can pass the ARN from ChildStack2 to ChildStack 1 using `Fn::GetAtt`

```
"Resources": {
  "ChildStack1": {
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
    "Properties": {
      "Parameters": {
        "ChildStack2Name": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["ChildStack2", "Outputs.StackName"]}
        "LambdaExecutionRoleArn": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["ChildStack2", "Outputs.LambdaExecutionRoleARN"]}
      },

      ....
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, Popoi. But what if I need to reference multiple resources from ChildStack2 in ChildStack1? Creating a separate parameter for each resource looks like an overhead. Are there any best practices to achieve that?